# Utilizing two php variables in mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not sure if I am apporaching this in the best way, but what I am trying to do is use two php variables for a IN clause in a mysql select query.

```
"select * from `user` where '$phpvar1' IN ('$phpvar2')"
```

Normally instead of $phpvar1 I would use a column name in the `user` table and it works fine, however in my case now I need the $phpvar1 variable to be used as a temporary column in this specific select query. Since $phpvar1 is dynamic in each situation, I do not want to store it. What can I do? Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, `$phpvar1` is not a column in the table, but I want it to act as one only for this one query. In this query I want `$phpvar1` which is equal to for example: "cat", where as "cat" is the data that would be found in the column, and then this data ("cat") would be used in the IN clause to see if `$phpvar2` contains "cat"

Basically what I want it to do is this:

```
SELECT * from `users` where 'mouse' IN ('cat', 'dog') and `userID` = '1'
```

the rows returned should have a userID = 1 AND meet the IN clause, since 'mouse' is not in ('cat,'dog') there won't be any rows returned in this case.

Comment: Did you executed the query.?

Comment: Are you just trying to insert the value of the PHP variables into the MySQL string?

Comment: Give this a try: ``"select * from `user` where `$phpvar1` in ('$phpvar2')"``.  Also how is your `$phpvar2` formed?

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with your approach. but in normal cases the we use field names instead of variable as the field names are fixed in the table. As @vee mentioned you should not use quotes around your field names

Comment: you just want to know if the 'cat' exists in the list `$phpvar2`? you can use a table less query `SELECT 'cat' IN ('cat', 'dog')` will return 1 and `SELECT 'mouse' IN ('cat', 'dog')` will return 0

Comment: after re-reading your question it becomes more confusing...

Comment: bansi, you're correct but I need this select as part of a larger query that uses a table. Something like this: `SELECT * from \`users\` where 'mouse' IN ('cat', 'dog') and \`userID\` = '1'`. So the results will return rows where userID = 1 AND ONLY if 'mouse' is in ('cat', 'dog)

Comment: the query you posted at the end is perfectly valid! and exact for your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your query to:

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE '$phpvar1' IN ('".implode("', '", $phpvar2)."') and `userID` = '1'"
```

Assuming that `$phpvar2` is array containing values to check for.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just noticed :)

Comment: This does not do what I want it to. MySQL is seeing `$phpvar1` as a column which does not exist.

Comment: @user1965476 Ok, I got what you want, but your approach is wrong. You define temporary fields in `select` part of the query. Than what is your `where` part? It will be like `"select *, \`$phpvar1\` from \`user\` where ..."`

Comment: @user1965476 Maybe you simple need the following `SELECT * FROM \`user\` WHERE \`$phpvar2\` = '$phpvar1'` (assuming `$phpvar2` is table column and `$phpvar1` is query parameter to check for, if no, than I need more clarification)

Comment: Neither $phpvar1 or $phpvar2 are columns, both are just php variables, however I want to compare them in the select statement and for them to determine the query result

Comment: @user1965476 First you can't compare two PHP variables in SQL query with `IN`. It is for checking whether the value is `IN` column. Second that what is your `WHERE` part in SQL. You must have `column = something` in where, or there's no any reason to use `WHERE`. Better clarify in your question with little example, so that we can understand and help you. Your query is wrong for the result you want. You are approaching it incorrectly I think.

Comment: @ArmanP. You may need to quote the strings `IN ('".implode("', '", $phpvar2)."')`

Comment: @bansi Thanks, I've updated the answer with quotes. That the result of posting some code without checking if it's actually working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $sql = "select * from `user` where ".$phpvar1." in (".$phpvar2.")";
```

Comment: No sanitizing? Tsk tsk tsk

Answer (score 0):

Your php variable should be in the select part
        Select $phpvar,otherstuff,  from user where x in ('$phpvar2');